# Set image for lockscreen in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to set an image as lockscreen which gets images from the the Flickr API. On Windows Phone 8.0 I used `LockScreenManager` and `LockScreen`, but I can't get it to work on windows phone 8.1.

Details: Code that I want to replace in windows phone 8.1:

```
bool hasAccessForLockScreen = LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication;

if(!hasAccessForLockScreen)
{
    var accessRequested = await LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync();
    hasAccessForLockScreen = (accessRequested == LockScreenRequestResult.Granted);
}

if(hasAccessLockScreen)
{
    Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/"+BackgroundRoot+fileName,UriKind.Absolute);
    LockScreen.SetImageUri(imgUri);
}
```

Comment: http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8-1-preview-developers/279529-wp8-1-lockscreen-how-customize.html

Answer (score 4):

There are currently no API's available for 3rd party application to set lock screen images in new Windows Phone 8.1 XAML based application.

If you want to use `LockScreenManager` for Windows Phone 8.1 then you need to target the `Silverlight version of 8.1`, It works on the 8.0 Silverlight API's, so you will be able to change the lock screen image.

This tutorials will help you understand better [Building Apps for Windows Phone 8.1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1).